# Is $\varnothing$ a limit ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

This question is from Goldrei's Classic Set Theory:

> Let $\lambda$ be an ordinal. If $\cup\lambda=\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal.

But what if $\lambda=\varnothing$? I think I am doing something wrong by writing $\cup\varnothing=\varnothing$.

Comment: You’re not doing anything wrong. It’s frequently useful to treat $0$ as a limit ordinal, since it’s not a successor ordinal, and that definition does so.

Comment: I've always taken $0$ to be a limit ordinal, and I've never encountered a case where it is of any use to consider it not to be one. What you write is correct; the empty union is the empty set!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One often defines a limit-ordinal as an ordinal which is not $\emptyset$ yet satisfies your mentioned properties. So no, $\emptyset$ is not a limit ordinal, though some authors may use it as a limitordinal since it in some sences behave as one, and it may make some proofs easier.

See also [the wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

The definition that I know is that all ordinals are successor ordinals, limit ordinals or 0. I believe this answers your question.

Comment: Is it the one given in Goldrei's *Classic Set Theory* ?